# Devastated about bachelor's thesis result - is there anything I can do?

Tags: bachelor

This week I defended my bachelor's thesis in a STEM field. I did everything my supervisor asked and also had time to do some extra work, since I had been working intensely from the start. (I was later told that this is a rarity, so I was proud of myself.) About a month before deadline I sent a draft with data and graphs to my supervisor. His comments were short and only positive. I asked him if he thought I had done enough work, if he thought there was anything I should be looking into, etc. He seemed to think it was more than enough.

Since he only had positive comments like "looks good" and so on, I thought I must have done a good job -  so I was blindsided when he suddenly criticized me at the defense. He thought I should have included an extra graph. I explained why I hadn't created such a graph, that I was focusing on a certain aspect of the data to support a point I was making, but he subtracted an entire grade from my result. The extra graph was something he thought would have been interesting, but it wasn't directly related to the point I was making, which is why I never thought of creating it.

I keep going over it in my head, but I don't see how I could have predicted that he would have liked that extra graph. I sent him my final graphs a month in advance, asked him if there was anything more I should do, and he suggested taking a look at a certain article if I wanted to, but nothing pertaining to the extra graph. There are numerous ways I could have expanded my thesis, I didn't know that he wanted me to expand it in this particular direction. I would have been more than happy to create more graphs if there had been any sort of hint that I should have gone in that direction, but there never was. Yet I feel like I should have figured it out somehow.

The grade I have received is viewed upon as mediocre in the environment I'm in, and I'm anxious about the way it will make me look, applying for a Master's degree. I'm very sad. I know of others who did not have time to finish all the work, let alone do extra work, and received a better grade (with different supervisors). I truly tried to do everything and think of ways to improve my thesis and it seems I was successful, apart from one graph. The other committee member seemed happy with my work. At some point while I was waiting outside the door I heard the committee member saying "well if you really think she should have done more...", which suggests to me he probably would have given me a better grade if it weren't for my supervisor.

How should I handle this situation? I wish I could forget about it and move on, but it's very hard for me. I put so much work into my thesis and it seems like it's all going down the drain because I failed to include a certain graph. Is it possible that I got unlucky? I feel like a failure. I would just like to know if there's anything I can do to improve my situation somehow.

For the record, I'm in a European country.

Comment: There are so many scenarios of why this might have happened running through my head right now that will make it extremely hard to write a full answer. However, I can tell you this. Professors can be moody, egotistic, nice and caring at any time of the day for no/a million reason! Let it go and do not over think it. I doubt that one missing graph from a BSc thesis would have ruined it all (not saying that it could not, but since he saw your thesis earlier, he would not have missed such a significant graph). Many professor like to encourage their students using negative reinforcement techniques.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a little. I think what hurts so much is how I blame myself. I don't know of any excellent students that received a grade like this for their thesis. I think less of myself now, although I'm trying not to.

Comment: "Here's the story of my life, what should I do?" questions are frowned upon on this website. Could you make your question more general, so that it presents a case that could apply to other viewers in future?

Comment: It's not a story of my life, it's asking about opportunities to help improve one's academic trajectory or otherwise coping, after experiencing academic failure. You don't think that could apply to others?

Comment: Getting a lower grade is not an academic failure! I know you might be a little emotional now (maybe?), if so, trust me, do not be! This may make you a little happy or sad (depends on the way you see it), but even if you added that figure, your thesis won't be perfect! There will always be something missing! If somebody points something out, that does not mean it is the only thing missing!! If you are this good at the BSc level, be twice as good at your MSc. Three times better at your PhD. That should be your motivation. Welcome to Academia my friend :)

Comment: I agree with you Fire Guy, but that just makes it seem all the more arbitrary that my supervisor decided to criticize me for it. It makes me feel like pursuing good grades is a bit meaningless. My motivation is very low at the moment. Thank you for the kind words though.